Performing a FFT using Accelerate in Swift using a sample rate that is not a power of 2
I am trying to perform a FFT on audio signals using Accelerate in Swift. My function takes in an audio signal as a [Float], converts it to the SplitComplex format that is required, and then uses the vDSP_fft_zrip() function. All of the setup for this function is taken from Apple's Documentation, but I can only get my code to work properly when the following two criteria are met:

The number of elements in the initial audio signal (the [Float]) is a power of 2. This makes sense since FFTs are optimized with powers of 2.

The sample rate of the initial audio signal is also a power of 2. This is the part that does not make sense to me. I want to use audio signals with a sample rate of 44100 Hz, which is not a power of 2.


The first criterion is understandable and I can easily conform my code to it by either slicing my initial audio signal or padding it with 0s. However, I don't want to change the sample rate of my audio file.
I want to know if it is possible to use the vDSP_fft_zrip() function on audio signals with a sample rate that is not a power of 2 (preferably 44100 Hz), or if I should use the DFT functions, which offer more flexibility at the cost of efficiency.
In other words, do I need to keep debugging my code or is this task simply impossible/unrealistic.
To test my FFT function, I created a sine wave using this function in Apple's Documentation:
func synthesizeSignal(frequencyAmplitudePairs: [(f: Float, a: Float)],
                             count: Int) -> [Float] {
    
    let tau: Float = .pi * 2
    let signal: [Float] = (0 ..< count).map { index in
        frequencyAmplitudePairs.reduce(0) { accumulator, frequenciesAmplitudePair in
            let normalizedIndex = Float(index) / Float(count)
            return accumulator + sin(normalizedIndex * frequenciesAmplitudePair.f * tau) * frequenciesAmplitudePair.a
        }
    }
    
    return signal
}

All of my tests had this frequency-amplitude pair: (f: 30.0, a: 1)
I first tried passing count: 4096, which created a wave with frequency of 30Hz at a sample rate of 4096, and the array length was 4096. This signal was transformed correctly
Next I passed count: 44100, which created a wave with frequency of 30Hz at a sample rate of 44100 and an array length of 44100. I padded the array with 0s so that its length would be 65536 (the next power of two). This signal did not transform correctly

Although in prehistoric times 2^N FFTs were a lot faster than other radix that is no longer true so if you use a more complete FFT library there is no reason it cannot support a data record length of 44100 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7^2 if memory serves. You have to understand that the FFT has implicit periodic boundary conditions so that whatever array you transform has been placed nose to tail along the time axis. This causes trouble if your waveform is not periodic on the chosen baseline. Windowing or resampling is the way out depending on your needs.

There is no requirement that sample rates be a power of two. There's no sample rate in an FFT; just samples. The sample rate just tells you how to interpret the output.
Your problem in all likelihood is your comment that you're padding with zeros. Zeros are not meaningless in samples. Switching from a pure sine wave instantly to silence represents significant high-frequency components in your signal, so you should see those show up in the FFT output.
Similarly, when you slice a random section out of your data, the transform is designed to assume this is exactly one period of a periodic function that continues forever (well, "an integer number of periods"). Unless things line up perfectly, you will get "spectral leakage" which takes the form of erroneous extra frequencies reported. This cannot be completely fixed, but it can be significantly improved by applying a windowing function. A fairly common one is a Hann window, but different windows have different properties and trade-offs.
This is covered in the same sample code you're currently consulting. See Reducing spectral leakage with windowing.
